# React Query v3 useInfiniteQuery returns isLoading, isFetching always true and isFetchingNextPage always false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have implemented infinite scroll with **useInfiniteQuery** from **react-query v3**. But **isLoading**, **isFetching** is **always true** after first page query. And **isFetchingNextPage** is always false. After initial load first page, next page requests is made with **fetchNextPage()**

This my **useContents** hook.

```
const useContents = (params) => {
    return useInfiniteQuery(
        ['contents', params.Section],
        ({ pageParam = 0 }) => fetchContents(pageParam, params), {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
                if (lastPage.payload.size === PAGE_SIZE) return allPages.length;
                return false;
            },
            refetchInterval: 60000,
            staleTime: 60000,
        }
    );
};
```

And this is **fetchContents**

```
const fetchContents = (pageParam, params) => {
    return axios
        .get(`${apiDomain}/contents`, {
            params: {
                Section: params.Section,
                ViewType: params.ViewType,
                Count: pageParam*PAGE_SIZE,
                PageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
                ...params.questionSectionParam,
            },
            ...generateAxiosOptions('GET'),
        })
        .then((res) => {
            return {
                message: res.data.message,
                payload: fromJS(res.data.payload),
                result: res.data.result,
                status: res.status,
                pageParam,
            };
        });
};
```

I have spent hours but couldn't find the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's a silly mistake. I added a scroll event listener to ref coming from props with an empty array. Below the wrong code and fixed by removing the empty array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  !!contentListRef && contentListRef.addEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroller, false);
  return () => {
    lastScrollTop = 0;
    contentListRef.removeEventListener('scroll', infiniteScroller, false);
  };
}, []); // <-- This empty array is the reason for this bug
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *isRefecting* works perfectly fine for me except for using *isFetching*.

```
{isRefetching && <GlobalLoading />}
```